# Upgrading bash on mac

Tags: bash, macos, version

I've tried to upgrade my bash version on my Macbook Pro (Mojave OS). To do this, I've run:

```
brew install bash
sudo nano /etc/shells # And then added the new bash shell to the bottom of the list. 
chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.11/bin/bash
```

After doing this, `bash -version` still returns version 3 but `echo $BASH_VERSION` print's version 5. If I try and make an associative array (I think this isn't present in 3), it works, so I assume I am using the new shell. Why has my bash version not updated?

Comment: Is it possible that you're running your new bash, but the command `bash` is still pointing to the original one? What does `which bash` give you?

Comment: which bash gives me only the original shell. It doesn't seem to be able to find the other one?

Answer (score 4):

Although you are running your updated version of bash, the command `bash` is (without a full path) still pointing to the original bundled version: `/usr/bin/bash`.

Assuming that you actually need to call the command in this form, then you should check the order of locations in $PATH, and make sure that the `bin/` folder with the new `bash` command is in the $PATH list before `/usr/bin`. Failing that, make an alias in the shell pointing to the new bash.

Answer (score 0):

`brew` adds the `bash` executable to `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

I think this should work:

```
brew install bash
sudo nano /etc/shells # And then add /usr/local/bin/bash to the bottom of the list. 
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```